# How to create a search system in Website using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to web development and I want to create a search system on my webpage, but I dont have any idea how to?

This search system must be able to search everything that is displayed on the webpage.

Please help me.

Comment: If you are new to web development in PHP, you should start smaller. Don't implement a search engine as your first project. (Lucene is the correct answer, but still requires a lot of work.)

Comment: @mario, I am just looking if there is any easy way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google Site Search:
http://www.google.com/sitesearch/

That's the easiest way. There are other ways (Lucene, Solr, etc) but for most applications -- especially if you're just starting out -- Google Site Search is more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html).  It's a port of the well-regarded Apache Lucene search system.

Comment: but it's a framework, i am not so experienced in PHP, I think going for a framework would be a big jump for me. Any basic approach?

Comment: It's well-documented, so I think it should be easier to use than some random script.

Comment: He's looking for an _easy_ way, and he's just starting out. Lucene gets complicated quickly even for an experienced developer!

Answer (score -5):

you can use strpos

http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php